# Could this be considered an elementary equivalent proof of the Banach-Tarski Paradox?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Note: I am overly dependent on the David Kung Great Courses Lecture on Banach-Tarski so I know I am over my head, but this seems basic. Since basic things can be easy to not understand I would like your opinion on this. This looks at how far Set Theory can push Decimal Notation.

Cantor showed how you could place two different points into one point by alternating their decimal digits, for example if you had a first point 0.111111... and a second point 0.222222...
you could make them into the one point 0.121212121212...  .

So if you have a unit sphere centered at the origin you could decompose every point in the first sphere into two points and reassemble those points into the relative position of the original point of the sphere where the first decomposed point was placed at a new sphere centered at the point (3,0) and the second point was reassembled into a sphere centered at the point (6,0) you would have taken apart the first sphere by the use of Decimal Notation and reassembled two spheres. (I did not want the headache of the Unit Spheres sharing any points, that can wait for later.)

One could also think about combining two unit spheres centered at (3,0) and (6,0) into a unit sphere centered at (0,0).

Of course there would be no reason to stop at just two spheres. And you should be able to scale up or down easy enough for a Meta Banach-Tarski Paradox.

1 Has this been proposed before?

2 If this is not legal, could you explain why? Do you have any recommended readings that would be good to try to read that could help to clear up my misunderstandings? Does it involve the Axiom of Choice? Is this from me not understanding Decimal Notation or different types of mappings?

3 How would this be any different from what Banach-Tarski did since you get the same result? They seem to divide it up into a finite number of sets, one sphere is a finite set? They take apart one sphere and create two spheres, so don’t they (by a simplistic mapping) make one point into two also? Are you allowed to say that every point in the original sphere can be mapped to two points so Banach-Tarski can’t be a bijection, so it has to be a surjection just like Decimal Notation? If you look at any specific point in the original sphere can you say that original point went to both spheres? If it did not go to both spheres it had to only go to one sphere so the other would be missing something so the resulting spheres would not be exactly the same, and that does not seem to be in the spirit of the Banach-Tarski Paradox.

I imagine it could be possible for one point in the original sphere to go to two points in one of the created spheres while another original point could go to two points in the other created sphere (as the second simplest case). Would you say my wanting to make a simple surjection of one sphere to two spheres from Decimal Notation being able to make one point into two (or more) points at the heart of my misunderstanding? But this seems so basic and Cantor loved Decimal Notation.

Answer (score 4):

Your construction is (roughly) legal, but it splits the sphere up into infinitely many individual points in order to rearrange them into two spheres. If you allow this, you're essentially just showing that these two sets have the same [cardinality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality). The Banach-Tarski theorem is the much stronger statement that you can split a sphere into *finitely many pieces* and assemble two copies of the original sphere simply by translating and rotating these pieces.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning Cardinality. Any suggested books you think might help me understand this better?

Comment: It sounds like you've got some intuition about cardinality already - the "alternating decimal digits" idea shows that $\mathbb R$ (the set of all real numbers) and $\mathbb R^2$ (the set of all pairs of real numbers) have the same cardinality. Another fun cardinality-related thought experiment is [Hilbert's hotel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_paradox_of_the_Grand_Hotel). For a more technical understanding of the formalisms necessary to appreciate the Axiom of Choice, I'd recommend any introductory set theory textbook.